# Strange optimization of "if" conditions in Java

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

I have decided to check the Java Compiler's perspicacity; thus, I have written a simple class.

```
public class Foo {
    public Foo(boolean a, int b) {
        if (a == true && a != false) {
            b = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I was wondering whether the compiler will optimize the condition to something simpler like:

```
if (a == true) {}
```

I compiled the class and then disassembled it with the `javap` tool. When I took a look at the output, I was truly dumbfounded, because the compiler checks both of these conditions, what is clearly shown below.

```
Compiled from "Foo.java"
public class Foo {
  public Foo(boolean, int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: iload_1
       5: iconst_1
       6: if_icmpne     15
       9: iload_1
      10: ifeq          15
      13: iconst_1
      14: istore_2
      15: return
}
```

I am just curious, why is it executing redundant instructions, when it can be optimized to something simpler?

Comment: It doesn't have to be a common use case. Compilers are intended to foresee and prevent from compiling things that make no sense.

Comment: @itachi Not really. There are lots of stupid ways to write code, and writing optimizations for all of them would make the compiler hard to maintain and prone to bugs itself.

Comment: After completely reversing Minecraft, I can safely say Java does very little, if any, semantic optimizations.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `javac` does no or only little optimization. The optimization occures during just-in-time (JIT) compilation of the bytecode.
This makes sense, because with this approach you can optimize differently for different target platforms and gain maximum optimization results.